# Visual C++ 2010/2008 does not accept `__int64` in C mode

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I have reduced the problem to these lines:

```
typedef __int64 int64;
inline int64 qatoll(const char *nptr) { return _atoi64(nptr); }
```

When compiling in C mode with VC++2008 or 2010 I get errors:

```
t.c(2) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
t.c(2) : error C2085: 'qatoll' : not in formal parameter list
t.c(2) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

In C++ mode it does accept the function definition and only complains about `_atoi64`.
What is the problem and how can I fix it?
Visual C++ 15 compiles it without errors, so is this related to C99 support?

Comment: It is not the `__int64` which is the problem, but the `inline` syntax which should be `_inline` (I just tried similar code on an older machine running MSVC 2008).

Comment: @HansPassant: interesting, but it happens even when I'm just using `cl /c t.c` without any extra switches.

Comment: @WeatherVane: indeed, it seems to be the issue. care to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the `__int64` which is the problem, but the `inline` syntax which should be `_inline`.

I just tried similar code on an older machine running MSVC 2008 to verify this.

Comment: yep, ["The **inline** keyword is available only in C++"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88(v=vs.100).aspx). Thanks!